# How to use Validate.js with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validate.js

I'm a beginner full stack developer that starting to build portal in my work.
The server side will develop in asp.net mvc 5 and the client side was(HTML, CSS, SASS, JS) developed by another company and I will develop the rest of the client side for example: security, handle request and response...

My problem is the company that developed the client side using Vue.js and I want to using with Validate.js library to secure the forms and another things in my portal but after a little search in google I didn't found any examples or explanation how to using Validate.js with Vue.js

From my searching I saw that Vue.js can handle the secure forms but i need to developing it my self and it's known that it's best to use the library that developed for this purpose.

So anyone can explain me how to use Validate.js with Vue.js or if I wrong explain me what to do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: There is even Vee-validate.js that is actually made for validation with Vue. In case if that suffices your problem, you can go through it over here. http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are two common *validators* that are used with `VueJs`.

- [`vuelidate`](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#getting-started)
- [`VeeValidate`](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/)

Comment: Your answer should have been a comment instead. It doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> When it comes to form validation, Vuetify has a multitude of
>   integrations and baked in functionality. Want to use a 3rd party
>   validation plugin? Out of the box you can use Vee-validate and
>   Vuelidate.
>   https://vuetifyjs.com/components/forms